# Unidentifiable character in stream reader

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

My goal is too collect duplicate characters and shorten them in a text file so,
aaaaa will result in 5a and or aabbb will result in 2a3b

At the end of line the loop is supposed to detect the /n character and then end the line. The problem is it finds a character which is not seen in the original text file and the new *CoMpReSsEd* one before the new line.

If I give the program this in the file

```
aaaaa
bbccc
```

It outputs this in the new file

```
5a1
2b3c1
1
```

I thought it could be some rogue space but I checked the file and after the 1 there is nothing.
Then thought maybe it was something like a null value so I added an if statement to check for 0x0 which didn't return anything.

```
        char CurrentCharacter = ' ';
        char PreviousCharacter = ' ';
        bool newline = false;
        bool FoundSymbol = false;
        string CurrentLine = "";

        int Counter = 1;

        for (int y = 0; y < Lines-1; y++) //minus one line as one is meta data
        {
            newline = false;
            CurrentCharacter = ' ';
            PreviousCharacter = 'n'; //n just means ignore character before basically this is appropiate when a new line happens or a different symbol
            CurrentLine = "\n";

            Console.WriteLine("New Line starting");
            while (newline == false)
            {
                //reading lines

                FoundSymbol = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Finding new Symbol");
                Counter = 1;

                while (FoundSymbol == false)
                {
                    CurrentCharacter = (char)FileReader.Read();

                    if (CurrentCharacter == PreviousCharacter)
                    {
                        //same character ++ to counter
                        Counter++;

                        Console.WriteLine("Same Character: {0} {1}" ,Counter ,CurrentCharacter);
                    }

                    else if (PreviousCharacter == 'n')  //is previous character as this what its comparing it too
                    {
                        //nothing its just reading the first character of the new symbol
                        //theres probably a better way than using n as a placeholder
                        Console.WriteLine("Placeholder Previous");
                        Console.WriteLine("Current Char: {0}", CurrentCharacter);
                    }

                    else if (CurrentCharacter == '\n')
                    {
                        //theres a new line so create symbol for current character and count and reset loop
                        CurrentLine += Convert.ToString(Counter) + PreviousCharacter;
                                                   
                        newline = true;
                        FoundSymbol = true;

                        Console.WriteLine("End of Line");
                    }

                    else if (CurrentCharacter != PreviousCharacter)
                    {
                        CurrentLine += Convert.ToString(Counter) + PreviousCharacter;
                        //are not the same so new character symbol is added to list
                        Console.WriteLine("Different Symbol: {0}" ,CurrentCharacter);

                        FoundSymbol = true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("What");
                    }

                    
                    PreviousCharacter = CurrentCharacter;
                    Console.WriteLine("New Previous character: {0}" ,PreviousCharacter);

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
           
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished Line {0}: {1}", y, CurrentLine);
            Console.ReadLine();

            File.AppendAllText(SaveLocation ,CurrentLine);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the code for it, Ignore anything to do with metadata as this is just some numbers on the first line which is copied across and works fine and my comments are scuffed so ignore those if you want.
This was the output from where the issue occurs.

[image]

I then added a second output on the same if statement of CurrentCharacter != PreviousCharacter as shown here at some attempt of finding out what it actually is.

```
                    else if (CurrentCharacter != PreviousCharacter)
                    {
                        CurrentLine += Convert.ToString(Counter) + PreviousCharacter;
                        //are not the same so new character symbol is added to list
                        Console.WriteLine("Different Symbol: {0} Test: {1}", CurrentCharacter ,CurrentCharacter);

                        FoundSymbol = true;
                    }
```

This then gave me this as an output

[image]

Obviously its entirely removed the outputted text before it so I just ended up being more confused  and here I am now. Any help would be appreciated ,sorry if this was badly written honestly im kinda scared of asking questions on here lmao.

Comment: You a probably not seeing the character because it's a control character and not printable.  I would guess that you are accounting for '\n' but if this is a windows new line it might be '\r\n'.  The best way to confirm this is to put a breakpoint on the output line and review it manually, or if that is not possible cast the output character as an int - which will give you a numeric representation of the character and check that against the ASCII table.

Comment: If the text file is coming from a pc running windows then the end of the line is garanteed to end with \r\n and this explains the 1\r most likely. You can detect it easily by using a debugger instead of simply relying on the output. Learning how to use a debugger is an important skill. Maybe even more important than coding itself, as you will find yourself hunting for bugs most of your time. It is a pity that teachers don't spend more time in learning how to use a debugger. As this excercise is most likely a school task correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thankyou both ,this makes a lot of sense now to why its going wrong. @PhilipStuyck and its actually a program that I've been doing for a few years now slowly adding stuff. It converts videos into text and replays them through the console. So as you'd expect when you have a 20min video at 24 fps at 240*180 characters it can make some very big files.

Comment: I would also use a text reader, in that case you read line by line, and it will be more performant most likely.If reading char by char is not buffered then you will have a performance issue. The Textreader class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader?view=net-6.0 provides a readline method. This will make the code more clear as you don't need the logic anymore to detect the end of the line.